# Calling a typescript function named in a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Ionic2 app. I am calling a function from a a Page. Is it possible that I use a variable name in function call. e.g.

original code: `this._userDataService.getGrandQuestionsFromServer(this.passedId, newLevel)`

expected code::

```
this._userDataService.get`${this.questionModuleName}`QuestionsFromServer(this.passedId, newLevel)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with bracket notation. Here is a working example:

```js
const obj = {
  foobar(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
};

const bar = "bar";
obj[`foo${bar}`]("It works!");
```

In your code, please try this:

```
this._userDataService[`get${this.questionModuleName}QuestionsFromServer`](this.passedId, newLevel)
```

Comment: But if you'd change `const bar = "bar"` to `const bar = "b"+"ar"`, typescript complains (\`foo${bar}\` cant be used to index obj)

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called `Tagged template literals`

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged template
> literals. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function.
> The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string
> values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. In the
> end, your function can return your manipulated string (or it can
> return something completely different as described in the next
> example). The name of the function used for the tag can be named
> whatever you want.
> [MDN - Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)

You can use it to preprocess the string and generate the function call you want.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can:

```
class A {
  callFunction(name:string) {
    this[`get${name}`](name);
  }

  getAmount(name: string) {
    alert(name);
  }
}

let a = new A();
a.callFunction('Amount');
```